# Get Altitude, Bearing, speed and GPS Accuracy

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

Hy guys, i need to find altitude, bearing and gps accuracy in my iPhone app. i've done this on my android app. in android, i did it like this :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (isBetterLocation(location, lastValidLocation)
                        && isEnable) {
                    lastValidLocation = location;

                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    altitude = location.getAltitude();
                    speed = location.getSpeed();
                    accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    bearing = location.getBearing();
                    locationProvider = location.getProvider();

                    onPositionChanged(
                            LocationService.this,
                            new GeoPoint(location.getLongitude(), location
                                    .getLatitude()));
                }
            }
```

how can i do the same thing in iOS ? 
i've tried to get it from CLLocation, but it return null/0,0000/-1.0000 .. 
btw, i get this result when i test it on iOS Simulator.
Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator is not a good place to test Core Location stuff. It only simulates a specific location but if you want to test speed, bearing etc. you're better of trying on a real device.

You need to use the class `CLLocationManager` ([Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)) and fetch the data using the delegate protocol available. For example, if you want the heading you implement the method `locationManager:didUpdateHeading:` and call the method `startUpdatingHeading` on the location manager.

Comment: mmmm so it because i'm using simulator . okay @Rick i will try to use real device . thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to get back if it still doesn't work, otherwise, consider marking my answer as accepted :)